# Touch issues in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

In Firefox 56.0.2 and before, it is really easy to copy texts and drag pictures (and save them) simply by moving across your finger on the screen; a simple double touch on a word on the box of google translate selects it and gives you the meaning of that word; rearranging the tabs also can happen by moving them with your finger.

None of the above no longer works in the new versions of Firefox (Firefox Quantum). I tried to find add-ons to make touch experience with Firefox Quantum less bothersome but to no avail. I'm trying to stick to the Firefox 56 but it keeps updating (although I have disable the automatic update), so for now I need to uninstall and reinstall older versions of Firefox every few days.

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody can help me solve this problem.